# Set user_property to send notification with FCM

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I’m using Firebase Cloud Messaging, for PushNotification service.
In Firebase console, I can send a notification to a specific user_property.

[FireBase Push Notification Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXsTe.png)

But I want to send it from the webserver, How can I set user_property in my request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option is currently only available when sending a message through the Firebase Notifications Console.

Only workaround I could think of in order to do this from your own server is if you track a similar property for each user and query the tokens for the corresponding ones and send the message to them accordingly.